# Looking for suggestion on microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

I took a course on using microcontroller of Intel 8051 long times ago. Recently, I am going to develop a module to control precise-timed TTL output and my instructor suggests to use microcontroller (MCU) instead of something like 555 timer. I am planning to get one for trial but I really don't have much experience on that.

My project is to create a time sequence with interval about 0.01 to 0.5 microsecond with function generator, which required the sampling frequency of the fun generator to be about 5 to 100MHz. But using function generator is not portable and I cannot program the function besides creating the timed sequence. I cannot generating that sequence with PC because the minimum time interval for interrupt is 1ms and it is too long for generating such short time interval pulses. Also, more importantly, even I generating 1ms-interval pulses with PC, since I don't have the real-time system, it doesn't generate time pulses at the expected interval precisely. Do you think MCU's interrupt is in real-time, i.e. how precise if I want to generate pulses like in 0.1ms for example?

I am also thinking an extreme case with super short pulse (1ns), does any sort of MCU support that short of interval?

My last question is about the code writer. I remember it needs a flash burner and compiler to feed the code into the chip 8051 while I was taking my course. But they got a development board in lab so everything go in one step. I wonder how does it works in practical development. Do I have to buy something like flash writer to write the code to the chip? The layout of the chips are different from manufacturers to manufacturers, so does it mean I have to buy different flash writer for different model? My budget for chip (and writer if needed) is about 20 bucks to 40 bucks. Any model to suggest is highly welcomed.

Comment: From a budget perspective I personally like using an [Arduino as ISP (In-circuit Serial Programmer)](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) for programming AVR's (ATtiny and ATmega). Those are slightly different from 8051, but if you know one, the other one is pretty easy to grasp.

Comment: 8051 instruction set microcontrollers are still available from [Silicon labs](http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/pages/8051-microcontroller.aspx), 
[Atmel](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/8051Architecture/default.aspx) etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern dev or evaluation kits tend to come with all needed bits needed to get the MCU programmed and running. Some are more generous than others, by working for many different microcontrollers, while others will only work with the specific MCU or Line of MCUs that it comes with. And they are a lot cheaper than they used to, with a larger scale of potential buyers, the ease of computers and USB being well, universal and very cheap to create for.

One specific line that I like is the [Texas Instruments ecosystem of Launchpads](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/home_head.html?DCMP=Value_Line&HQS=launchpad). They have the ValueLine MSP430s, small general purpose microcontrollers. There is the USB F5xxx Launchpad, the bigger brother of the Valueline, and allows for USB Peripheral programming. They have the Tiva C and Hercules ARM Launchpads, if you want to move more towards low end computing microcontrollers. A variety of them, and all come with the FET debuggers for programming and debugging, and between 5 and 30 dollars depending on which one you get.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am a bit confusing due to the some technical terms I don't know before. So I think the 5 to 30 dollars is for the MCU only, so do I need an additional flash writer?

Comment: @user1285419 5 to 30 dollars is for the entire dev board, including the MCU. The Value Line Launchpad is 10 dollars now, includes two Microcontrollers worth ~1 dollar in 1k units (~2+ dollars each single quantities), a usb cable, a crystal oscillator, an extra set of 10 pin female headers, and the board with the programmer/debugging.

Comment: @user1285419 what I meant in the beginning of the answer is that most development kits have the microcontroller(s) AND the writers combined.

Comment: that sound so cool. I am reading the spec. It seems that it is pretty easy to use. I just have one question. for the dev board, the MCU is integrated into the board so if I want to develop some product, I have to apply the who board instead of just the MCU to my circuit, right? So I cannot take the MCU off the dev board an apply them to other circuit alone, is that right?

Comment: @user1285419 depends on which you use. The Value Line chips are DIP ics in a socket, so you can remove them easily. The other ones are not in a socket because they are smd ics, but the dev boards have connectors for the programming pins that allow you to connect a separate board with extra microcontrollers on them, for programming and debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Beware that you are asking for opinions, which can be a reason for closing your question.

You stated both "clock frequency as high as possible" and "not that expensive", without quantifying either. This forces us answerers to guess what you actually want. Better state what you want to achieve (in terms of the timing of the waveform to be generated).

That said, I can suggest three routes (out of the many more that are possible):

- go for an Arduino. complete hardware, including bootloader. lots of community support. Downside: the development environment is targeted (also) at non-techies, so you are somewaht shielded from the details.
- go for Microchip PICs. Get a bare chip (18F4520 just to mention one), a breadboard, and a programmer (pickit2 or pickit3). You will be forced much more into the details than with the Arduino.
- go for 32-bit, my suggestion would be the Cortex M0 LPC1114. I prefer C++, but C or asm is equally viable. You'll need a serial interface to connect to th chip and download a program (I use lpc21isp as tool on the PC).

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding question. I am just starting and I don't have much idea. But I am planning to have the timing controlled in 0.01 to 0.1 microsecond so the frequency should be about 10 to 100 MHz (the timing I generated with PC is about 80MHz). I wonder if the price will be so high if I go up to 100MHz or even above. I know that some chips like 8051 is pretty cheap but I don't know others. I am controlling the price for the MCU to less than 20 bucks. What I am worrying about is how much for the code/flash writer.

Comment: 100 MHz is too much for the micro-controllers I know to generate anything under software control. If you really need such resolution an FPGA might be a better choice.

Comment: Some one suggests FPGA to me also. But it seems FPGA is pretty expensive. I search for some MCU products online and some of them are supported CPU up to 120MHz. I wonder is it the same thing for the clock frequency and the CPU working frequency?

Comment: A CPU clock frequency of 100 MHz does not imply that you can use it to produce a waveform with 10 ns resolution. As a ballpark, 50 ns would probably be doable with some assembler fiddling.

Comment: Thanks. So what technical parameter determines the time resolution then? Is any MCU supporting real-time clock in application?

Comment: No single parameter. The CPU clock, number of cycles per instructions, instruction set, buses, memory, and I/O hardware all contribute.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion if you want to use MCU from Microchip, thats what I use, is search in the [MAPS](http://www.microchip.com/maps/microcontroller.aspx) (Microchip Advanced Part Selector) hotsite, that you could choose the MCU like you want, by the features, the price, clock, etc.

Comment: that's good place to search for my need. I just worry in what way how write the code to the chip and how much do I spend on the writer?